# Google Photos transfer from account to account

Tags: photos, google-photos

I know there's no easy solution but I'd like to transfer a collection of photos form Jan 2006 to Jan 2022 from an original google account to another one so that that space will be accounted instead of running out of space.

Pleeeese HOw to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com)
2. Select Google Photos
   [image]
3. Select the Albums you need by clicking on "All photo albums included"
   [image]

4. Scroll down and click "Next step"
5. Select the options you need and click "Create export"
6. You will receive an email once the export is complete
7. Download the ZIP file using the link in the email
8. Extract the ZIP file
9. Visit [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com) and upload the images like you normally would (by dragging-and-dropping or by click upload)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did...